# Being logged out of Area 51

Tags: bug

I am a native speaker of Greek (and German) and I realised there was an Area 51 proposal for Greek, so I rushed to offer my expertise :p

But each time I click on a question - while being logged in - I become logged out and the site says I have to log in. I do that, but end up on the main page, where upon the whole thing repeats.

Comment: Note that you still have to confirm your email on Area 51 (I think so, since you didn't get the 50 reputation you should get from this). I don't know whether this is the cause, but it might be.

Comment: Also maybe relevant: On your profile, it is shown that you are a follower (https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/171186/ludi). But you are not in the list of followers: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101509/greek-language

Comment: Confirmed. Seems to not have solved it. I might need to wait a while.